# How to define ticks with out knowing the range of x-axis and y-axis in flot chart

Tags: jquery, charts, customization, axis, flot

I would like to draw a flot chart. The challenge is that date range of x-axis will vary from days,weeks,months,years...

Also the y-axis will vary from 10,100,1000...

how I can accommodate the above variations in single flot chart.

Comment: `flot` will auto-generate appropriate ticks for you.  How are you unhappy with how it does this?  What would you like the ticks to be formatted differently?

Comment: i tried to implement date as x axis with orderbars...the following library throws error jquery.flot.orderbars.js. This is not allowing me to auto-generate ticks

Comment: Can you build a [Code snippet](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) etc. which shows your problem?

Comment: @Raidri, Thanks, I used fiddle to solve it. Data format issue for one of the bars...

Comment: I face the same problem..Can anyone please post answer or snippet of code on fiddle?

Comment: @KaushalBhatt , Can you please make sure the date is in unix time stamp and multiplied by 1000. This is because flot accepts only  milli seconds

1451606400 Is equivalent to  01/01/2016 @ 12:00am (UTC)

Flot  value should be 1451606400 *1000 which is 1451606400000